# Error: "You attempted to use a firebase module not installed on your Android project" when using @react-native-firebase/dynamic-links in expo app

Tags: expo, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I am trying to implement dynamic linking in my Expo app using the @react-native-firebase/dynamic-links package. However, I am encountering an error and need assistance resolving it.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
const handleDynamicLink = (link: any) => {
  console.log(link);
  // Handle dynamic link inside your own application
};

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);
  return () => unsubscribe(); // Remove the listener when the component is unmounted
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  dynamicLinks()
    .getInitialLink()
    .then((link: any) => {
      console.log(link);
      // Perform additional actions based on the initial link
    });
}, []);
```

The error message I am receiving is:
"Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app(). Ensure you have imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file and added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside the RN 'getPackages()' method list."

I am aware that using react-native-firebase directly in an Expo app is not supported, but I would like to know how to make the dynamicLinks component work in my Expo app.

Comment: Did you find a work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use rnfirebase in an **expo go app**, but on an expo app built with `prebuild` or `eas build` it works.

What you may try doing is **rebuilding your app** after installing apps that use `bare react native` like rnfirebase.

Comment: So, I have to comment out that piece of code every time i am in development environment?

Comment: Just use ```eas build development```, download the app that eas builds for you install it in your device run your environment with ```npx expo start --dev-client```, use that as your development environment you can use any package there.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to set up dynamic linking in expo that just works?